# iOS - What happens I lost my APNs Key file?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I just created the APNs Key file from Apple Developer website. It was saying "Don't lost this key". I already have a backup but what happens if I lost it?

It is also saying I just need one APNs Key for all apps.

Can I create more than one APNs Key or should I go with just one? If I lost this am I going to can't send notifications for just that app or none of my apps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need private APN key to send notifications. You will unable to send notification if you lost the key.

Comment: Just for the apps registered with this key or all of my apps which I am going to publish in the future? @MichaelVorontsov

Comment: Are you asking about .p8 file or ...

Comment: Asking about both. What happens if I lost it? Can I create more than one? Should I use it for all apps or just for one app? @Krunal

Comment: Definitely you can create other. You just can't use old.

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelVorontsov

Comment: I think there is a limitation in creating key with APN service. There'll be error such as "You have already reached the maximum allowed number of Keys for this service". But it's not clear how many could we have and how do we increase the limit. I'd like to pay more if needed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have MULTIPLE `.p8` files. The `.p8` file is used to generate a `JWT Token` on the server side and that is used to send push notifications via `HTTP2` to Apple's APNS server. Only problem is that if you lose it, you have to regenerate a new one on the server side. It doesn't affect existing apps at all because it's bound to the bundleId, applicationId, and developer account.

In other words, it's not a certificate that the app has to be re-signed with or anything.

Scenario to make it simpler:

- I create an app called `MyApp` with BundleId: `com.SO.myApp`.
- I create an APNS `.p8` file with account `RT8NCD`.
- On the server side, I use this .p8 file to send notifications to `com.SO.myApp` via `HTTP2` and `JWT Token` generation.
- I release the app to the AppStore.
- I then LOST the `.p8` file and can't send push to my app which is already on the store!

What do I do?

- I go into the developer portal and re-create a NEW `.p8` file with the same AppId and BundleId and same account.
- Then on the server side I use this `.p8` file to send push notifications to the devices registered in my database.
- I do not need to release a new app or new version or anything.

So in other words, there's not really any consequences to `losing` it.. but it's not a good idea to get into the practice of losing keys, certificates, etc.. Seriously.

P.S. I cannot guarantee that this behaviour won't change in the future. It's Apple. Try not to lose things.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking. Thank you for clearing this out.

Comment: @Brandon A question, what happen if we revoke an existing keys? Does all application that already installed by user will also be affected?

Comment: @fajarainul **You should create a new key first**, then test push notifications using that new key on your push server. Finally/Lastly, revoke the old key. If you revoke the old key first, you won't be able to revert it and your app will be affected **until** you setup a new key and test it with your server. It is the same as losing a key, you have to create a new one, and revoke the old one, so the same rules apply.

Comment: This clarified everything I've been looking for for the last hour. Very clear and concise answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can create one APN key per app (one for development one for production) but also you can recreate it, and all devices which was registered with all APN will be supported by new key

Comment: I am not asking .p12 file. I am asking about "APNs", ".p8" file.